# How to disable launch modal dialog in list definition schema.xml?

Tags: list-definition, dialog-framework

I have a sharepoint 2010 site template. The site template activates a feature that deploys several lists. Some lists need to open the new/edit/display forms in full page mode.

Is there a way to disable the Launch dialog option in declarative way in the schema.xml file?

Answer (score 12):

The property mentioned by djeeg works if it is set on the list element in your schema.xml:

```
<List Title="A List Definition"
      ...
      NavigateForFormsPages="TRUE">
```

This is the equivalent to setting "Launch forms in a dialog" to "No" under advanced list settings. It doesn't show up in the schema, but I've verified that it is still effective.

Answer (score 2):

I dont think there is.

The code property is NavigateForFormsPages

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.navigateforformspages.aspx

But it doesnt appear on either the list or listinstance schema

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms415091.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms476062.aspx

I did a little test, created a new list, then set the property through the browser, then saved the list as a template. There is a property NavigateForFormsPages exported in the template manifest.xml

```
<List Name="{DE7BBD17-2A35-434C-B8C4-DEB257F40DB3}" Title="ImportData" Description="" Direction="0" BaseType="1" FeatureId="{00BFEA71-E717-4E80-AA17-D0C71B360101}" SendToLocation="|" ServerTemplate="101" Url="ImportData" VersioningEnabled="TRUE" MajorVersionLimit="0" MajorWithMinorVersionsLimit="0" DisableAttachments="TRUE" NavigateForFormsPages="TRUE" BrowserFileHandling="permissive" Version="4">
```

But the exported value doesnt match what you set in the UI, it is always TRUE.

Even if you edit the manifest.xml, set the property FALSE, re-package and create a new list, sharepoint still ignores the value.

Comment: I'm not sure why you don't see the UI respect your list settings, but setting NavigateForFormsPages="TRUE" on the list element in my schema.xml works as expected. Keep in mind that "TRUE" is reflected as "No" in the List's Advanced Settings->Launch Forms as Dialogs page.

Comment: Visual Studio complains that the attribute does not exist, but setting is as described by bojolais works for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can change it with powershell: Have a look if this is what you want. http://get-spscripts.com/2010/10/change-sharepoint-list-settings-using.html