# Programmatic Setting List Options

Tags: list, list-definition

In the list definition, is there a way to programmatically set the "Dialogs" parameters?

I see available parameters such as OnQuickLaunch, as well as the parameters listed: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms415091.aspx

However, I am interested in setting the list definition in a way that it will not launch forms in a dialog by default.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A similar if not identical question was asked [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/8243/how-to-disable-launch-modal-dialog-in-list-definition-schema-xml).  Is this what you need?

Comment: This is perfect.  Thank you.  I tried searching for similar, but guess I did not do a very good job.